# Slicing a Pandas dataframe with a non monotonic index gives unexpected results

Tags: python, datetime, pandas, slice

Sorry this is a basic question about slicing in pandas. Say I create a dataframe with a non-monotonic index:

```
df1 = pd.concat( [ pd.DataFrame( randn(2,2), index=pd.date_range('2014/01/01', periods=2) ), 
                  pd.DataFrame( randn(2,2), index=pd.date_range('2013/01/01', periods=2) ), ] )
```

Output:

```
             0           1
2014-01-01   0.493182   -2.115045
2014-01-02   0.773144   -0.857416
2013-01-01  -1.048656   -0.066363
2013-01-02   0.022071    0.034887
```

The following works as expected:

```
df1[ pd.Timestamp('2013-01-01'): ]
```

Output

```
             0           1
2013-01-01  -1.048656   -0.066363
2013-01-02   0.022071    0.034887
```

But if I do the following:

```
df1[ '2013-01-01': ]
```

I get this:

```
             0           1
2014-01-01   0.493182   -2.115045
2014-01-02   0.773144   -0.857416
2013-01-01  -1.048656   -0.066363
2013-01-02   0.022071    0.034887
```

Why does this return the whole dataframe when the index is not monotonic?

Comment: http://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/timeseries.html#datetimeindex, specifically the note there is probably what you're running into. Perhaps use `df1.loc['2013-01-01':]`. By just using df1['str':] your using special syntax for DatetimeIndexes that assumes the index is sorted.